# WSO2 Identity Server (IS) Account Disabling Option(Checkbox) is Not Available in the Default Profile

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm using WSO2 IS 5.3.0 in a clustered environment. I followed the documentation in order to enable the account disabling feature.
Currently, the account disabling option is not available for the default profile of users, even after I checked the box "Supported by Default" for the relevant claim.

What could possibly be wrong? Am I missing something?

Any suggestive approach to solve this issue is much appreciated. Thanks.

[claim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvmmk.png)

[default profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEyNc.png)

Comment: The user `test` is in the `Primary` user store? If not, you have to add an claim-attribute mapping for that user store as well. (Can be done from the same place where you are setting supported by default)

Comment: Thanks, @NipunThathsara for the reply. The user "test" is in a JDBC user store. Do I need to add a claim attribute mapping separately as well if that's the case?

Comment: If that's JDBC, no need. JDBC user stores doesn't require attribute mappings. Btw, do you have multiple nodes in a cluster? If so, this could be a caching issue if you haven't configured clustering properly. You can verify this by shut down and starting all the nodes

Comment: @NipunThathsara Yes, there are 2 nodes in the cluster. Therefore, yes it could be a caching issue. I will try the node restarting approach. Thanks again for the quick response.

Comment: @NipunThathsara I tried restarting both the nodes and checked the default profile, but still no luck. Any other suggestive approach would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @LilanMihiranga What is the behavior if any other identity claim/user claim is made as "support by default"? eg: Enable support by default option in "Account Locked"(which is an identity claim) and "Full Name" (which is a user claim) and check whether they will be displayed in the user profile or not?

Comment: @AnuradhaKarunarathna I made the claims as "Supported by Default" for Account Locked and Full Name as per suggestion. Interestingly, they are not also been displayed in the user profile.